# Necesito actualizar un select en php sin refrescar la pagina

Tags: php, mysql

Chicos, busco de nuevo sabiduría en stack overflow...

Resulta que tengo un formulario de creación de cursos, en donde el usuario tiene la posibilidad de agregar uno o mas relatores desde un select, y si en este select no aparece el relator que quiere, o desea agregar uno nuevo, puse un botón que muestra un modal, y en este doy la posibilidad de agregar el relator a la BD,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El detalle esta en que, si bien no tiene problemas para guardar en la BD, el nuevo relator no se muestra de inmediato en el select, y hay que actualizar el sitio (F5) para que cargue el select con el nuevo relator agregado,

¿Como puedo solucionar este detalle?, había pensado en agregar un botón de actualizar en el select, pero no se como y si sera realmente eficiente...

Comment: ajax seria una buena opcion

Comment: La pregunta, en su formato actual, es muy amplia.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que utilizar Ajax, para esto necesitas llamar la librería de jQuery (en este caso) y colocar un evento en el botón "Guardar Relator" (un onclick estaría bien) y este evento iría a una función en Javascript que capture los datos del formulario, con estos re estructuras el select, algo asi:

```
function actualizarRelator(){
//capturamos los datos del formulario del modal
var nombre = $("#idCampoRelator").val();
var identidad = $("#idIdentidadRelator").val();

 $.ajax({
   method: "POST", //método de envió de datos
   url: "some.php", // pagina donde recibirá los datos
   // nombre de la variable: valor de la variable a enviar
   data: { nombre: nombre, identidad: identidad }
  })
  .done(function( res) {
   //respuesta en caso favorable del ajax
  //
  //agregas al select con el dato registrado

  ("#idSelect").append(´<option value="${res}" selected>nombre</option>´);

 })
 .error(err){
  // respuesta en caso de error
  console.error(err);
 };
// cierras el modal
}
```

hago uso los [backtick es6](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings). Espero que te sirva de guia y te sea de ayuda.

Comment: Se escribe backtick considera corregir

Comment: Gracias por la corrección